# Perform API call in background if Angular HTTP observable does not give response in n seconds

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am using Angular with RxJS observables for HTTP API calls in an Ionic/Angular application.

```
this.http
    .post('https://API URL', data, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(
        (res) => {},
        (err) => {}
    );
```

Requirement is that if the API request takes too much time say 10-12s to give success or error i.e 200 or 500, etc. response then I want to trigger some other modal popUp or ui element and keep the processing, the API request as it is, happening in the background and notifying on completion.

Comment: So what have you tried? You could, for example, start a separate timer observable with a `.delay` to trigger the modal and unsubscribe from it when the request finishes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not sure of how to do this , like you mean using an observable within an observable?

Comment: No, he means starting a separate observable, at the same time you send your HTTP request. For the rest, why not read the API documentation of the delay operator, and try something?

Comment: Not *within* it, no; start it in the component at the same time you trigger the request from the service. It's not up to the service to decide what should happen in the UI if the request takes a long time.

Comment: That would be `Observable.merge()` of the API request & something like `Observable.of('timeout!').delay(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're definitely many was to do this but I'd personally prefer this one where I'm keeping everything inside a single chain:

```
this.http.post(...)
  .merge(Observable.timer(10 * 1000)
    .do(() => /* Show a notification or whatever */)
    .filter(() => false) // Never pass through this value
  )
  .take(1) // This is required to complete the chain immediately after the source Observable emits without waiting for the merged one to complete as well
  .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You an use `timeout` method to achieve this.

```
this.http
    .post('https://API URL'  , data , {
        headers : headers
       })
    .timeout(10000) // 10 seconds
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
         (res) => {},
         (err)=>{ console.log(err)} // TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred
     );
```

Comment: This will kill the api call, while he wanted to keep waiting and just let the user know it's taking a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use takeUntil to cancel one observable when another emits a value. Share so you don't make two requests.

```
const source = this.http.post().pipe(share());
source.subscribe(console.log);
timer(10000).takeUntil(source).subscribe(() => console.log('It\'s taking over 10 sec'));
```